# Having problem while using docker-compose on mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm having a problem while trying to connect MySQL database using Docker-compose. My app starts until trying to connect to DB through docker while I can connect to the same DB from my IDE. 
While I run it from IDE with MySQL running  form Docker I can connect to it, add, delete etc using spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exchanger. 
But starting my app from docker-compose seem to cause connection errors. I tryied different datasource.url and nothing helps.

Here's my files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8u201-jdk-alpine3.9
ADD target/exchanger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar exchanger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'                          
services:                             

  db:
    container_name: db       
    image: mysql                     
    environment:                       
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exchanger
      MYSQL_USER: user
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
      - "33060:33060"
    restart : always
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql


  exchanger:                              
    build: ./                          
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:                        
      - db
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/exchanger
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=info
```

console log

```
Starting db ... done
Starting exchanger_exchanger_1 ... done
Attaching to db, exchanger_exchanger_1
db           | 2020-02-13 23:28:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian9 started.
db           | 2020-02-13 23:28:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db           | 2020-02-13 23:28:02+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian9 started.
db           | 2020-02-13T23:28:02.638670Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010139] [Server] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 8161)
db           | 2020-02-13T23:28:02.638684Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010142] [Server] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 4000)
db           | 2020-02-13T23:28:02.968321Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
db           | 2020-02-13T23:28:02.968508Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 1
db           | 2020-02-13T23:28:05.415554Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db           | 2020-02-13T23:28:05.461398Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db           | 2020-02-13T23:28:05.504622Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db           | 2020-02-13T23:28:05.777882Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
exchanger_1  | 
exchanger_1  |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
exchanger_1  |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
exchanger_1  | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
exchanger_1  |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
exchanger_1  |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
exchanger_1  |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
exchanger_1  |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)
exchanger_1  | 
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:06.865  INFO 1 --- [           main] p.e.exchanger.ExchangerApplication       : Starting ExchangerApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on f2c5f2d1f4c1 with PID 1 (/exchanger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /)
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:06.873  INFO 1 --- [           main] p.e.exchanger.ExchangerApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:09.180  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:09.341  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 138ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:10.311  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:10.944  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:10.976  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:10.976  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:11.128  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:11.128  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4140 ms
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:11.752  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:11.911  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:12.181  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:12.410  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
exchanger_1  | 2020-02-13 23:28:13.660 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
exchanger_1  | 
exchanger_1  | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
exchanger_1  | 
exchanger_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
exchanger_1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
exchanger_1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
exchanger_1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
exchanger_1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
exchanger_1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
exchanger_1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar!/:8.0.19]
exchanger_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
exchanger_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:354) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
exchanger_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
exchanger_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
exchanger_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:554) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
exchanger_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
exchanger_1  |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.2.jar!/:na]
exchanger_1  |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
exchanger_1  |  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar!/:5.4.10.Final]
...
```

Comment: It looks like the driver is for mysql 5.7 but the database version is 8. Could it be?

Comment: Did you check same thing in workbench or some other tool? Using defined credentials. In short, URL and other things are okay?

Comment: Can you re-execute project using localhost(or relevant host value) instead of container name(db) in application.configuration file?  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exchanger (docker running on same machine then localhost or if in other then put host value over their)

Comment: You need to expose 3306 port

Comment: Your setup is correct. Can you try and start the database first (docker-compose up -d db) and then the application (docker-compose up -d exchanger)? I have the feeling your only problem is that the database is not yet ready to accept connections. The times that you see in the log are the times when docker received the message, not when it really happened.

Comment: @Mihai you might be right, because I see the databases, user and password is created after main app exits. I wonder if there is any solution to invert the order of starting and running up containers

Comment: There is a solution but you need to implement it, it is not build in. There are lots of wait-for-it scripts available. You need to delay the start of your application until your can successfully connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem,

The problem occured during setting up database for first time. I thikn something went wrong while creating MySQL database and the whole volume ./myslq-data was wrong.

I've just deleted catalog mysql-data and created run docker-compose again. It created volume again and working great.